# capitalize first letter of each word in sentence

Tags: css

I know how to capitalize first letter in a sentence. But, how to capitalize first letter of each word ?

eg: i am there

```
::first-letter {
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

text changed as: "I am there". But, I am expecting, "I Am There". How to style this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502316/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

```
.text{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

You can read about it here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp