# How can I capitalize the first letter of each word using CSS I tried also other stake overflow questions but didn't work?

Tags: html, css

I need help to capitalize my every First letter of each word but don't know-how
I tried following but didn't work:-
[How can I capitalize the first letter of each word in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502316/how-can-i-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-css)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
       h1 {
          text-transform: lowercase;
          display: inline-block;
       }
       h1:first-letter {
           text-transform: uppercase
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>THIS IS TEST</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

but it result:- This is test

it only capitalizes T but I need I and T also...

please don't give a solution for JS

Comment: text-transform: capitalize; ? Just search on the documentation ;)

Comment: i searched but didn't get anythings

Comment: If your test is all uppercase it will show uppercase even if you use capitalize. You have to write it lowercase

Comment: @prshant your task is impossible to do with just PURE CSS

Comment: You can't do that with css only

Answer (score 1):

You need to use text-transform capitalize

```
   text-transform:capitalize;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
       h1 {
          text-transform:capitalize;
          display: inline-block;
       }
      
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>this is test</h1>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: buddy but in my case all HTML content get capital

Comment: Your html Content is all caps already <h1>THIS IS TEST</h1>

Comment: want to convert in to lower case then need to capitalize @lev

Comment: i tried but did't work